# Loop in R (probably too simple?)

Tags: r, loops

I am new to R and I somehow didn't get yet how to code a loop properly. Of course, I checked some manuals and forum entries. But I may just have been too, well, stupid. Shame on me. Here is my problem:

I would like to load pecisely 44 mini-datasets (each representing one year (they are called year1871.csv, year1872.csv, etc.). I guess, a loop would help here to load all the individual CSVs. Basically I want the loop to do the three lines below for each CSV. But I really don't know how to code that.

`year1871= read.csv("year1871.csv", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
year1871$stateA = factor(year1871$stateA)
year1871$stateB = factor(year1871$stateB)`

`year1872= read.csv("year1872.csv", stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
year1872$stateA = factor(year1872$stateA)
year1872$stateB = factor(year1872$stateB)`

`...`

If anyone could help, that would be fantastic. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you did not try very hard, start with:

```
for (i in 1:50 ) { 
     ...
}
```

`i` will take values between 1 and 50.

to create an empty list:

```
els = list()
```

to create year02.csv in a string you can do:

```
i = 2
num = formatC(i, width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0") 
filename = paste("year", num, ".csv", sep="")
print(filename)
```

to add an element called list01, you can do the following:

```
listname = paste("year", num, sep="")
els[[listname]] = read.csv(filename, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```

Now you just have to joint the parts together.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found myself the answer:

```
for (i in 1871:1914) {
                  assign(
                          paste("year", i, sep=""), 
                          read.csv(
                                    paste("year", i,".csv", sep=""), 
                                    stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
                        )
                  }
```

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score -1):

you really haven't tried hard enough yet... but here are some pointers

```
l=list()
for(i in 1:50){
  name=""
  if(i<10){
    name=paste("year0",i,sep="")
  } else {
    name=paste("year",i,sep="")
  }
  filename=paste(name,".csv" ,sep="") 
  # your file reading stuff here      

  l[[name]]$stateA="the thing from the file" # use [[ to create a column to the list l 
}
```

this will result in a list l
which has 50 lists, each having a stateA, stateB etc..